# React JS ref (useRef): contains is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-ref, use-ref

I am working on a React JS project. I am using hooks and functional components. I am using ref. I am using useRef because I am in a functional component. But the contains function is not working on ref. Following is my code.

```
const App = () => {
    let refDialog = useRef(null);
    
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (refDialog && refDialog.contains(e.target)) {
         // I will do something here
      }
    })
   
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog ref={ ref => refDialog = ref}>My dialog content</Dialog>
     </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see in my component, in the event listener, it is throwing the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: refDialog.contains is not a function
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Uhm, I think you have a typo at useRf it should be `useRef` and you want to make sure that `current` property exists on refDialog and check the contains on refDialog.current

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is refDialog.current!!

Comment: I tried refDialog.current as well. It is not working.

Comment: I don't think contains is what you're looking for in the first place. You're checking whether the current property of the refDialog object equals the target of the click. 
So, shouldnt that either by ```ìncludes`` in the case of a list of things or simply ```===``` if you're checking for identity?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working version of your problem,

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

// YOUR OTHER IMPORT GOES HERE

const App = () => {
    const dialogRef = React.useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener("click", handleClickElement, false);
        // THIS WILL REMOVE THE LISTENER ON UNMOUNT
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickElement, false);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleClickElement = event => {
        if (dialogRef.current && dialogRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
            // YOUR LOGIC
            console.log("Am Clicked!")
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog ref={dialogRef}>My dialog content</Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove typo - `useRf` -> `useRef`. Secondly - `refDialog` is a read-only variable, you can't overwrite it - `ref={refDialog}` is enough (without ref function). Finally - `refDialog` will hold an object with `current` field. So the final condition will be:

```
if (refDialog.current && refDialog.current.contains(e.target))
```

Comment: @WaiYanHein You tried what? Everything what I described above?

Comment: Yes. I did try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`Dialog` may not be handling refs internally. In such case, you can wrap it inside a `div` (it will not have the same exact effect, but it probably just work fine nonetheless):

```js
const App = () => {
  const refDialog = useRef(null);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = e => {
    if (refDialog.current?.contains(e.target)) {
      // I will do something here
    }
  }
   
  return (
    <div ref={refDialog}>
       <Dialog}>My dialog content</Dialog>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Also, notice the use of `useEffect`, the way your code is defined, with every render, a new event listener is being created and not cleared. You probably only want to do this once when the component is created.

If Dialog is a component you defined, you need to make sure the ref is being passed correctly using a [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

```js
const Dialog = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} className="Dialog">{ props.children}</div
));
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work:

```
import React from "react";
const App2 = () => {
  let refDialog = React.useRef(null);

  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (
      refDialog &&
      refDialog.current &&
      refDialog.current.contains(e.target)
    ) {
      console.log("xx");
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={refDialog}>My dialog content</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You had a typo in useRef.
You need to check if current property exists on refDialog.
Unlike its class counterpart, useRef hook doesn't return DOM node directly.